# Pentaho Kettle Database Repository

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Currently we have multiple file based kettle repositories, we are planning to move them to database . Some of these repositories have transformations with same name, we have a oracle back end and when we are trying to import the repositories into the schema generated by kettle the repositories with the same name are getting overwritten or skipped. Does it mean that there needs to be a separate schema in oracle for each repository ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create different folders on the root of your DB repo for each of the file repos. When you import you specify the target folder. This way they are kept separate.

Just remember to change your schedules or invocation scripts to point to the right location.